# Seaborn is saving the same figure when calling a function multiple times

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using a function to save sns scatter plots, when I call this function multiples times within a script, for different plots, it saves the same figure multiple times, like the first figure is overwriting the others.

If I call the function only once in the script, it saves the correct plot.

```
def plot_projection(X, y, name):
    data = pd.DataFrame({name+'_1': X[:,0], name+'_2': X[:, 1], 'class': y})
    sns_plot = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=name+'_1', y=name+'_2', hue='class', legend='full')
    fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(name)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I found how to fix, just need to call `plt.clf()` at the end of the function, so it clears the current figure.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own answers. [It is actually encouraged to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can find this in the tutorial, here I just summarize it:

`plt.cla()`:  Clear the current figure.

`plt.clf()`:  Clear the current axes.

`plt.close()`: Close the window.

As for the definition of `figure`, `axes`, and `window`, you can find them in the tutorial too.

Remember when you want to call the drawing in a `function` you need to clear it. Or the content will be in one same figure.

```
def plot_projection(X, y, name):
    data = pd.DataFrame({name+'_1': X[:,0], name+'_2': X[:, 1], 'class': y})
    sns_plot = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=name+'_1', y=name+'_2', hue='class', legend='full')
    fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(name)
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: Better. Thanks for updating.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your help! I am still learning to do a better job. Thank you!